# Meteor simple schema and collection2 autoValue only firing once

Tags: javascript, meteor

I can't get autoValue to fire more than once, even though the docs suggest it always runs:

```
var saleItem = new SimpleSchema({
    productId: {
        label: 'Product Id',
        type: String
    },
    sku: {
        label: 'Item Name',
        type: String
    },
    name: {
        label: 'Item Name',
        type: String
    },
    price: {
        label: 'Item Price',
        type: Number,
        decimal: true,
        min: 0
    },
    qty: {
        label: 'Item Quantity',
        type: Number,
        min: 0
    },
    subtotal: {
        label: 'Item Subtotal',
        type: Number,
        decimal: true,
        autoValue: function(doc) {
            console.log(doc);
            return doc.$push.items.price * doc.$push.items.qty;
        }
    }
});
```

The console logs a JSON document the first time the document is inserted, but not thereafter. It's important to note that this schema is a sub-schema.

Comment: I suspect this is because sub-schemas are somehow not validated, I think I read that somewhere, can anyone confirm?